# How to have extra permalink for posts

Tags: permalinks

My permalinks are like mydomain.com/post and have to be like that, but because I use non-English characters (which need to be in the URL and make it really long and weird) for posting in social networks I need to have an extra permalink like mydomain.com/?p=123 (or something like that but with my exact domain).

P.S: I searched and came across yourls.org which is great but I'm not sure if I can have in the same directory as Wordpress!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use the post ID to link to a page, like this:

```
http://yourdomain.tld/?p=1234
```

You can find out the Post ID right from the post overview screen. If you hover over the "Edit" or "Delete" link, you can see that the URL has a parameter `post=`. The number behind that is your page ID.

It could happen, that WordPress redirects your "post ID permalink" to the "real" version with the slug, but you are good to use the numeric one for linking.

Comment: I´m glad I could help so far. Did you have something different in mind, because you wrote "kinda"? Maybe there´s something better for your needs.

Comment: First I thought it is gonna be just a start but I went with it and now I'm sure your help (though simple) was all I needed.

Comment: @MaiTemp if this post answers your question, please, mark it as the "accepted answer" (check mark under up/down vote buttons). This will help to other users to find the correct answer easily and quickly.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to have two links pointing to the same Page or Post.there are two approaches:

1. Install SEO for Yoast plugin and  use its Canonical url ability
2. choose page/post slug to a short elegant one (recommended)

Comment: how is any of both options answers the question?

Comment: The URL format `mydomain.com/?p=123` is the default URL for posts. If "pretty" permalinks are on, this URL will be redirected to the "pretty" one with 301 status code. Also, you must know that WordPress already sets the canonial link for posts wihtout any plugin.